# R - plot a Venn diagramm with proportions of overlap

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to plot a Venn diagramm and I have the following specifications:

```
# size of g
g <- 97.22
# size of m
m <- 63.89

# overlaps
# i.e. the proportion of size m covered by g
g_covering_m <- 0.9015527
# i.e. the proportion of size g covered by m
m_covering_g <- 0.7253595



# the size of m covered by g
gm <- g_covering_m * m


# plotting
library(eulerr)
vennDiag <- euler(c("g" = g,
                    "m" = m, 
                    "g&m" = gm))
plot(vennDiag, counts = TRUE, 
    font=1, 
    cex=.1)
plot(vennDiag,
    edges = list(lty = 3),
    quantities = list(type = "counts", 
                      font = 3))
```

Obviously less than 0.9015527% (=`g_covering_m`) of the m circle is covered, because `eulerr` draws this by size.

Now I am wondering how I can get the circles to be drawn in a way, that it represents the specification that I have estimated?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: whether or not this is possible with the `eulerr` package, I strongly recommend against presenting data this way.  The area of the overlap region vs. the disk sizes is impossible to interpret visually with any accuracy.   If you want the audience to get this quantitative info, use  some version of a bar chart or similar layout.   If you haven't yet, read Ed Tufte's great books on effective presentation of data.

Comment: Meanwhile:  what is "size"  ?  area? radius?  Please be explicit in defining all terms

Comment: Thanks for your comment Carl. I disagree, though. Interpretability in this case is a matter of resolution. Don't be blended by all the decimal digits, resolution is not that important for me. A venn diagram is the best representation for this data.

Comment: oh and size is area. Altough it does not matter, it could be radius as well. Again, a matter of resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by default the `euler` function expects numeric values indicating the disjointed set sizes (A∖B, A∩B, B∖A), not their total size (i.e., union, A, B, A∩B). But you can easily change that by supplying the corresponding option:

```r
# sizes
g <- 97.22
m <- 63.89

# proportion of size coverages
g_covering_m <- 0.9015527
m_covering_g <- 0.7253595

# the size of m covered by g
gm <- g_covering_m * m

# plotting
library(eulerr)
vennDiag <- euler(c("g" = g, "m" = m, "g&m" = gm), input="union")
plot(vennDiag, edges = list(lty = 3),
     quantities = list(type = "counts", font = 3))
```

[image: result of above function with input type union]